# PubSub Error : AssertionError: A message queue should exist for every ordered message in flight

Tags: python, google-cloud-pubsub

currently I am developing publisher and subscriber in python program, this program is quite simple which i found somewhere in github

```
def receive_messages(project_id, subscription_name):
    subscriber = pubsub_v1.SubscriberClient()
    subscription_path = subscriber.subscription_path(project_id, subscription_name)

    def callback(message):
        msg_data = message.data.decode("utf-8")
        log_message(f"Processing message in parallel: {msg_data}")
        # Simulate processing time
        time.sleep(10)
        #log_message(f"Finished processing message in parallel: {msg_data}")
        message.ack()
        log_message(f"Finished ack message in parallel: | {msg_data}")

    with subscriber:
        executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(128)
        flow_control = pubsub_v1.types.FlowControl(max_messages=1024)
        scheduler = pubsub_v1.subscriber.scheduler.ThreadScheduler(executor=executor)
        streaming_pull_future = subscriber.subscribe(
            subscription_path, callback=callback, scheduler=scheduler, flow_control=flow_control
        )

        try:
            # Wait for messages in parallel
            streaming_pull_future.result()
        except TimeoutError:
            streaming_pull_future.cancel()
            print("TimeoutError...")
        except BaseException as be:
            streaming_pull_future.cancel()
        finally:
            print("cdcoff")
            sys.exit(1)

receive_messages(PROJECT_ID, SUBSCRIPTION_NAME)
```

but sometimes i got error like below

```
google.cloud.pubsub_v1.subscriber._protocol.helper_threads;ERROR;Error in queue callback worker: A message queue should exist for every ordered message in flight.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_protocol/helper_threads.py", line 118, in __call__
    self._callback(items)
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_protocol/dispatcher.py", line 187, in dispatch_callback
    self.ack(ack_requests)
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_protocol/dispatcher.py", line 247, in ack
    self.drop(requests_completed)
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_protocol/dispatcher.py", line 309, in drop
    self._manager.activate_ordering_keys(ordering_keys)
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_protocol/streaming_pull_manager.py", line 523, in activate_ordering_keys
    self._messages_on_hold.activate_ordering_keys(
  File "/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/_protocol/messages_on_hold.py", line 121, in activate_ordering_keys
    assert (
AssertionError: A message queue should exist for every ordered message in flight
```

but i am not yet found what causing this error, the subscriber is still fetching incoming message while throwing an error, any suggestion?

while in pubsub side, I checked the checkbox option to "Order messages with an ordering key
When enabled, messages tagged with the same ordering key will be received in the order they are published. This option cannot be changed later. "

Answer (score 0):

This was an [issue in the client library](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/issues/913) that was [fixed](https://github.com/googleapis/python-pubsub/pull/911). It was released in version 2.16.1 that was built on May 5, 2023. Ensure you have updated your client library version to one that includes the fix.